# How to translate text using api in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs and using nextjs and right now i have button "Translate",I want whenever
we click on "Translate" button then text(in english) should be convert to "arabic", For this i am using "translate-google-api",But i am getting "Error: Network Error",I tried with following code

```
const changelanguage = async() => {
    const result = await translate(`I'm fine.`, {
        tld: "cn",
        to: "vi",
      });
      console.log('language result is '+result);
};
 return(
 <button onClick={() => changelanguage()} >Translate</button>
 )
```

Comment: could you add the code for the `translate` function?

Comment: The "Error: Network Error" message is most likely caused by a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue.